# Implementing jQuery UI functionality in a Drupal Views template

Tags: jquery, drupal, user-interface, drupal-views

If I wanted to implement the jQuery UI tabs functionality to include a link to the anchor tag it references, and disable the default behavior, I know I need to write the code as such:

```
//slider nav images
Drupal.behaviors.slidernav = function(context) {
$('.slider-nav li a:not(.slidernav-processed)', context).addClass('slidernavprocessed').each(function(i) {
    $(this).append($("div#tabs-"+i).find(".slide-thumb").html());
   });
};

$(".slidernav-processed").click(function () {
  var link = $(this).attr('rel');
  window.location = link;
  return:false;
});
```

where it returns

```
<li class="ui-corner-top ui-state-default">
  <a rel="http://link.com" href="#tabs-0" class="slidernav-processed">
  content</a>
 </a>
</li>
```

I know how to set it up currently in the php for it to show the content, but how can I phrase this is the views template to place the link appropriately so?